# Integral when absolute inequality holds

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Suppose that $f_1,f_2:[0,\infty) \rightarrow ℝ, f_1,f_2 \in \mathcal{R}$, $\lvert f_1(x) \rvert \leq f_2(x) $ for all $x \geq 0 $. Prove that $\int_0^\infty {f_1(x)\mathrm dx}$ converges if $\int_0^\infty {f_2(x)\mathrm dx}$ converges.

*Here is my attempt:*

Since $-f_2(x) \leq f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) $, $-\int_0^x {f_2(t)dt} \leq \int_0^x {f_1(t)dt} \leq \int_0^x {f_2(t)dt} $ for all $x \geq 0 $. Meanwhile, let $\int_0^\infty {f_2(x)dx}=L$ so that there exists some $N$ such that $x \geq N$ implies $\lvert \int_0^x {f_2(t)dt} - L \rvert < \epsilon$, which is equivalent to $ L - \epsilon < \int_0^x {f_2(t)\mathrm dt} < L + \epsilon $, for an arbitraily small $\epsilon > 0$. Then, $-L - \epsilon < \int_0^x {f_1(t)\mathrm dt} < L + \epsilon $.

Now this tells that $\int_0^x {f_1(t)\mathrm dt}$ is bounded, but not that its limit converges. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f_1(x)dx| \leq \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f_2(x)dx \to 0$ as $x_2>x_1 \to \infty$. For any sequence $x_n \to \infty$ $(\int_{0}^{x_n} f_1(x)dx)$ is  Cauchy sequence , hence it has  a finite limit. I will let you check (using above inequality) that the limit does not depend on what sequence $(x_n)$ tending to $\infty$ you take.